# Pseudo class after/before displays with position static but not position absolute

Tags: css

I am using bootstrap 2. I have dropdowns that contain a variety of elements that fill the dropdown. I set overflow to hidden so that the border radius is retained. When position is set to absolute the pseudo before/after arrow disappears. They remain visible when position is static, but I must use position absolute.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

li {
    padding: 4px 10px;    
}

.dropdown-menu:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 16px;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 17px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdellara/4epZV/

Change position: static; to absolute in .dropdown to see example.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain all of your CSS, in particular the pseudo selectors are missing.

Comment: Fixed. Not sure how that happened, maybe I didn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have `overflow:hidden` set on `.dropdown-menu`, thus, if you absolutely position the pseudo elements outside of the element, they will not appear.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/jaWBR/) - `overflow:hidden` removed - it works now.

As for why `overflow:hidden` didn't work while the position was `static`, this is another question within itself, I couldn't find any relevant specs other than:

> **CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3** - 6.7. static
>
> The box is a normal box, laid out according to the normal flow. The ‘top’, ‘right’, ‘bottom’, and ‘left’ properties do not apply.

I would guess that it is because the element isn't positioned, thus there would be no overflow.

Comment: As stated in the question, I must use position:absolute and overflow:hidden, so the second part of your answer is, in fact, the question I am asking. Fixed positioning has the same effect as static, so it doesn't seem to have to do with whether or not the element is positioned. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements outside the actual element via a negative margin-top, `overflow: hidden` hides them.

Remove that and change to `position: absolute` and you're good.

http://jsfiddle.net/4epZV/2/